Data Shape Issues in SKL Pipeline using TFIDF
I am stumped on an issue with Python/Sci-Kit Learn/Pipelines. I am receiving an error that the shape of the data as it passes through the pipeline is not what is expected.
Specific error:
blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,6].shape[0] == 4, expected 794.

What I am sending into TFIDF
X['Subject'].head()
5          FW: Customer PO 345 \\ HAC 73054 and 7345
8                            Insured return request, o# 35693
10                             Issue with a new Feature - QAR
13                                       FW: ABC / TSS PO catchup
15    WTM request - 1deaSe sales orders for CDE PO TSSe9-1r9

The relevant code is below:
#FeatureSelector selects a list of columns from a data
#frame and returns them to a pipeline step for processing
class FeatureSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, keys, description = ""):
        self.keys = keys
        self.description = description
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print("Keys out", self.keys)
        return X[self.keys]

# Custom transformer to help with debugging. 
class Debugger(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, stepName = ""):
        self.stepName = stepName

    def transform(self, data): 
        print("Step Name", self.stepName)
        print("Contents of data", data.columns)
        print("Shape of Pre-processed Data:", data.shape)
        #print(pd.DataFrame(data).head())
        return data

    def fit(self, data, y=None, **fit_params):
        # No need to fit anything, because this is not an actual  transformation. 
        return self


y = df['Assigned To']
X = df

# Construct Pipelines
ohe_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("feature_selector", FeatureSelector(df.select_dtypes(exclude=['int64','object']).columns.to_list())),
    ('feature selector debugger', Debugger()),
    ("ohe", OneHotEncoder()),
    ('ohe debugger', Debugger())],
    verbose = True)
text_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("feature_selector", FeatureSelector(df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.to_list())),
    ('feature selector debugger', Debugger()),
    ("tfidf_vectorizer", TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf debugger', Debugger())], 
    verbose = True)

knn_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("feature_union", FeatureUnion([
        ("ohe_pipe", ohe_pipe),
        ("text_pipe", text_pipe)
        ])),
    ("classifier", KNeighborsClassifier())
    ])

knn_grid = GridSearchCV(
                     estimator=knn_pipe,
                     param_grid = {'classifier__n_neighbors': [x for x in range(5, 20, 1) if x % 2 != 0],
                                   'classifier__weights': ['distance'],
                                   'classifier__leaf_size': range(20,40,1),
                                   'feature_union__text_pipe__tfidf_vectorizer__min_df': [.01, .02, .03, .04, .05],
                                   'feature_union__text_pipe__tfidf_vectorizer__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], 
                                   'feature_union__text_pipe__tfidf_vectorizer__stop_words': ['english'],
                                   'feature_union__text_pipe__tfidf_vectorizer__lowercase': [True],
                                   'feature_union__ohe_pipe__ohe__sparse_output': [False]
                                   },
                     scoring = {'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score)
                                # ,
                                # 'f1': make_scorer(f1_score),
                                # 'precision': make_scorer(precision_score),
                                # 'recall': make_scorer(recall_score),
                                # 'roc_auc': make_scorer(roc_auc_score)
                                },
                     cv = 3, 
                     refit = 'accuracy', 
                     error_score='raise')
knn_grid.fit(X, y)

Following my debug trace, you can see, in bold below, that the TFIDF step is returning a shape of (1,1) rather than (529, 1). If I run all these steps (including TFIDF) outside of a pipeline, TFIDF returns (529,1). I would like to use the pipeline for the Grid Search capabilities.
Keys out ['Issue Classification', 'Application', 'Case Submitter']
[Pipeline] .. (step 1 of 4) Processing feature_selector, total=   0.0s
Step Name 
Shape of Pre-processed Data: (529, 3)
[Pipeline]  (step 2 of 4) Processing feature selector debugger, total=   0.0s
[Pipeline] ............... (step 3 of 4) Processing ohe, total=   0.0s
Step Name 
Shape of Pre-processed Data: (529, 66)
[Pipeline] ...... (step 4 of 4) Processing ohe debugger, total=   0.0s
Keys out ['Subject']
[Pipeline] .. (step 1 of 4) Processing feature_selector, total=   0.0s
Step Name 
Shape of Pre-processed Data: (529, 1)
[Pipeline]  (step 2 of 4) Processing feature selector debugger, total=   0.0s
[Pipeline] .. (step 3 of 4) Processing tfidf_vectorizer, total=   0.0s
Step Name 
**Shape of Pre-processed Data: (1, 1)
[Pipeline] .... (step 4 of 4) Processing tfidf debugger, total=   0.0s**


Not directly related to the error: Instead of FeatureUnions with your FeatureSelector, consider using ColumnTransformers.

@BenReiniger, thank you. I will research that. I am feeling like my current implementation is a bit bulky so thanks for suggesting a way to trim it down.

I think I have this figured out. After following the source definitions of TFIDFVectorizer which inherits (is that the way to say it in python?) from CountVectorizer, I was able to drop some print statements into the transform and _count_vocab methods in TFIDF and CV respectively.
I saw that while my dataframe column was successfully passing into the TFIDF transform method and then to the CV transform method and then to the CV _count_vocab method, when the _count_vocab method went to iterate through that dataframe column, it could not. The code from that implementation is below:
#print("REMOVE****** RawDocs in _count_vocab->", raw_documents)
values = _make_int_array()
indptr.append(0)
for doc in raw_documents:
    #MY ERROR Showed up Here, this for loop only iterated once
    #print("REMOVE****** Individual Doc in _count_vocab->", doc)
    feature_counter = {}
    for feature in analyze(doc):
        try:
            feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]
            if feature_idx not in feature_counter:
                feature_counter[feature_idx] = 1
            else:
                feature_counter[feature_idx] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # Ignore out-of-vocabulary items for fixed_vocab=True
            continue

The solution was to modify my FeatureSelector to include an option to return an iterable list rather than a data frame column.
I dont know how I was able to pass a data frame column when not using a pipeline but, this appears to work inside of a pipeline.

This is a common gotcha: while most sklearn objects expect a 2D array (or Dataframe etc.), the text transformers expect a 1D array (or Series etc.).  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65325103/10495893
